# Python3 change string to byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm using Python3.5 and I want to change `\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084` into `b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'`

But using `'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'.encode('ascii')` or `'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'.encode('utf-8')`doesn't work.

In `.encode('utf-8')`, it will become
`b'\xc3\xa1BA\x06\xc2\xbe\x084'`  differs from
`b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'`

How to deal with this?

Comment: It looks like that string should be a bytestring before it gets to your code. What library / interface is giving it to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `latin1` codec.

```
>>> '\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'.encode('latin1')
b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
```

The reason why this works (and is the way it is) because originally those bytes sequences were defined to be those characters by the [ISO-8859-1 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), and thus encoding them down back using that encoding well, gets you back those exact bytes.

While the other answer is useful (the loop through all available codecs to get all possible output is great), do keep in mind that while other specific codecs will work for some specific strings, it may or may not end up mapping to the identical base "byte" sequence.

```
>>> '\xfe'.encode('iso8859_9')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/iso8859_9.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xfe' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> '\xfe'.encode('latin1')
b'\xfe'
>>>
```

Of course, the `raw_unicode_escape` can be useful if your intent is to encode everything to a form of base byte encoding that also allow anything > `\xff` to be represented through the `\\uXXXX` form:

```
>>> 'あ'.encode('latin1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u3042' in position 0: ordinal not in range(256)
>>> 'あ'.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
b'\\u3042'
>>>
```

Naturally, pick the strategy that makes the most sense for your intent.

Comment: @Loïc legacy reasons, but I figured I post the answer right away before I edit in the explanation which I had to wiki because seriously I don't have all the various background in my head.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation.

Comment: @DaChen you're welcome, and I am surprised that this wasn't asked before because I can't seem to find a suitable duplicate entry for this question specifically for Python 3 and string conversion to identical raw byte sequence (they all talk about actual encoding, but not at the byte level).

Answer (score 1):

You can try all kind of encodings to see if it match what you want.

```
s = '\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'

code_list = ["ascii", "big5", "big5hkscs", "cp037", "cp424", "cp437", "cp500",
 "cp720", "cp737", "cp775", "cp850", "cp852", "cp855", "cp856", "cp857", "cp858",
 "cp860", "cp861", "cp862", "cp863", "cp864", "cp865", "cp866", "cp869", "cp874",
 "cp875", "cp932", "cp949", "cp950", "cp1006", "cp1026", "cp1140", "cp1250", "cp1251",
 "cp1252", "cp1253", "cp1254", "cp1255", "cp1256", "cp1257", "cp1258", "euc_jp",
 "euc_jis_2004", "euc_jisx0213", "euc_kr", "gb2312", "gbk", "gb18030", "hz", "iso2022_jp",
 "iso2022_jp_1", "iso2022_jp_2", "iso2022_jp_2004", "iso2022_jp_3", "iso2022_jp_ext",
 "iso2022_kr", "latin_1", "iso8859_2", "iso8859_3", "iso8859_4", "iso8859_5", "iso8859_6",
 "iso8859_7", "iso8859_8", "iso8859_9", "iso8859_10", "iso8859_13", "iso8859_14",
 "iso8859_15", "iso8859_16", "johab", "koi8_r", "koi8_u", "mac_cyrillic", "mac_greek",
 "mac_iceland", "mac_latin2", "mac_roman", "mac_turkish", "ptcp154", "shift_jis",
 "shift_jis_2004", "shift_jisx0213", "utf_32", "utf_32_be", "utf_32_le", "utf_16",
 "utf_16_be", "utf_16_le", "utf_7", "utf_8", "utf_8_sig", "idna", "mbcs", "palmos",
 "punycode", "raw_unicode_escape", "rot_13", "undefined", "unicode_escape",
  "base64_codec", "bz2_codec", "hex_codec", "quopri_codec",
 "string_escape"]



for i in code_list:
    try:
        if s.encode(i) == b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084':
            print('**{:>20}** ==> {}'.format(i, s.encode(i)))

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

RESULT:

```
**              cp1252** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**              cp1254** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**              cp1258** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**             latin_1** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**           iso8859_9** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**              palmos** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
**  raw_unicode_escape** ==> b'\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
```

Comment: This is quite a useful way. Thanks.